# Rounding of the lower back while doing squats

Tags: weightlifting, squats, starting-strength, weights, freeweights

I've been working with Starting Strength for a while now and although I've been taking lots of notes on form and watching videos wherever I can I can't stop rounding my back. I find that when I'm coming up from a squat I feel like I need to ditch the weight or 'round' my way up. Does anybody have any suggestions for preventing myself doing this and if possible without having to deload too much to do so?

Comment: How long? How much weight? Lower back or upper back rounding?

Comment: Do you know how to extend your back when you not with the bar? Like when you're sitting in your chair, or lying face down on the ground? What is the last weight you used that didn't result in back rounding?

Comment: Do you round your back with just the bar and no weight plates?

Comment: squeeze your shoulder blades together like you holding a $100 bill between your shoulder blades, punch chest up on ascent, force your knees out, point toes out slightly, put your elbows into the hips...focus just on that, then come back in 4-5 weeks and tell us if u still round ur back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andreas tips are great; also, look to the ceiling while doing the exercise.

I'm guessing that your lower back is the one that curves. That happens because its weak. You can strengthen it by doing dead lifts and/or lower back raises.

If you started to train recently, just do the lower back raises; start with 3 sets of 15 reps twice a week. I would do this for a whole month.

I've been training for a long time, years, but after a break of about 6 months; I had the same problem. What I did was:

- 3x15 lower back raises

Did this 3 days a week for 2 weeks.

Then I added the dead lifts, like this:

- 3x5  dead lifts
- 3x15 lower back raises

Did this 3 days a week for 2 weeks.

Comment: i'd also suggest a TON of reverse hyperextensions, make that a staple in your training diet